# How do I use Java to read a .csv file and insert its data into SQL Server?

Tags: java, sql-server

I am very new to Java. I have a task with two steps.

1. I want to read all data from a `.csv` file.
2. After reading that data I have to put it into a SQL Server database.

I have done step one. I'm able to read the `.csv` file data, but I don't know that how to insert it into a database.

Here's my code for fetching the `.csv` file data:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;  
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;  
import java.io.FileReader;  
import java.io.IOException;  
import java.util.StringTokenizer;  


public class DBcvsdataextractor {  

    /** 
     * @param args 
    */  
    public static void main(String[] args) { 
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub  

        String fileName="D:/USPresident Wikipedia URLs Thumbs HS.csv";  

        try {    
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader( new FileReader(fileName));    
            StringTokenizer st = null;    
            int lineNumber = 0, tokenNumber = 0;    

            while( (fileName = br.readLine()) != null)    
            {    

                if(lineNumber++ == 0)  
                   continue;                  

                //break comma separated line using ","    
                st = new StringTokenizer(fileName, ",");    

                while(st.hasMoreTokens())    
                {    
                    //display csv values    
                    tokenNumber++;    
                    System.out.print(st.nextToken() + '\t'); 
                }    

                //new line    
                System.out.println(" ");    

                //reset token number    
                tokenNumber = 0;    

            }    
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {    
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block    
            e.printStackTrace();    
        } catch (IOException e) {    
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block    
            e.printStackTrace();    
        }
    }
}
```

Now, how do I insert that data into SQL Server?

Comment: "if u have any code then share it with me" ??? That's totally wrong.

Comment: Hi gurung,,i have code that is already pasted by me,,and don't have any other code...by this code i m able to get the .csv files data but how to insert it into sql server table,,,if u have any code or suggestion then plz share it with me....

Comment: [Stop Rolling Your Own CSV Parser!](http://secretgeek.net/csv_trouble.asp) There are a lot CSV parsers out there that you can use.

Comment: @Rahul: Why are you doing it with java? SqlServer can import csv directly.

Comment: Hi Nikunj,,i m new in java,,,so if u have any suggestion or code for me related my question then plz share it with me... i will send u my email id u can forward ur code to my id..

Comment: Bjorn Pollex,i know we can do it directly using sqlbulkcopy,,,but the main thing is that our all project coding in using java that's why i m doing it with java...so if u have any suggestion then plz tell me....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want to do this with Java, and really want to write your own CSV parser as you currently did, you can

1. Instead of printing out each 'CSV-file value', you will have to store them. You could for example use an `ArrayList` for each column in the CSV file, and populate those while reading the CSV file
2. Once the file is read, you can loop over those `ArrayList` instances again to construct one big `INSERT` statement for all data, or one `INSERT` statement for each row you encountered in the CSV file. If you would opt for the last option, it is not even necessary to use those `ArrayList` instances. In that case you could construct an indiviual `INSERT` statement while reading the CSV file, and submit it to the DB after each time a row has been read.

I know the approach of constructing your query while reading the CSV file would be possible as well if you want to go for one big `INSERT` statement, but separating the `INSERT` from the reading of the CSV file has the big advantage you can replace your own CSV parser later on by a standard one without too much trouble.

Comment: Hi Robin..."System.out.print(st.nextToken() + '\t');",,here i m printing my values,,,but u r saying that i have to store data in arraylist,,,but when i m using arraylist for storing data,then program give me errors,,,so plz can u write arraylist code in place of "System.out.print(st.nextToken() + '\t'); " this line,,,and also something about insertion..

Comment: See http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0140__Collections/0160__ArrayList.htm for a set of tutorials on how to work with ArrayLists

Answer (score 5):

The SQL Server has a tool for this.

Like this:

```
BULK INSERT CSVTest
FROM 'c:\csvtest.txt'
WITH
(
FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',
ROWTERMINATOR = '\n'
)
```

Use this command in your java, using JDBC connection, for example.

Hope this helps.

[SQL Server file CSV](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/02/06/sql-server-import-csv-file-into-sql-server-using-bulk-insert-load-comma-delimited-file-into-sql-server/)

Comment: Hi Anderson Carniel,,Thanks for ur rply,,but i know about that logic means about"BULK INSERT",,,but the main problem is that we cannot handle exception through "BULK INSERT",,,,that's why i m not using it....

Answer (score 0):

You can customize below class to insert data into sql server.

File **ImportCsv.java**

```
package com.example.demo;

import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.Reader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;

import com.opencsv.CSVReader;

public class ImportCsv
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws UnsupportedEncodingException, FileNotFoundException
    {
            readCsv();
    }

    private static void readCsv() throws UnsupportedEncodingException, FileNotFoundException
    {
        Reader readerstream = new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream("D:\\file.csv"), "Unicode");
            try (CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(readerstream, ',');
                    
                    Connection connection = DBConnection.getConnection();)
            {
                    String insertQuery = "Insert into [dbo].[tableName] ([Column1],[Column2],[Column3], [Column4],...[Column8]") values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
                    PreparedStatement pstmt = connection.prepareStatement(insertQuery);
                    
                    String[] rowData = null;
                    int i = 0;
                    while((rowData = reader.readNext()) != null){
                    for (String data : rowData)
                    {
                        //System.out.println(new String(data.replace(" ","")));
                        String strLine = new String(data.replace(" ",""));
                        String[] splited = strLine.split("\\s+");
                        

                            pstmt.setNString(1, splited[0]);
                            pstmt.setNString(2, splited[1]);
                            pstmt.setNString(3, splited[2]);
                            pstmt.setNString(4, splited[3]);
                            pstmt.setNString(5, splited[4]);
                            pstmt.setNString(6, splited[5]);
                            pstmt.setNString(7, splited[6]);
                            try {
                            pstmt.setNString(8, splited[7]);
                            }catch(Exception e) {
                                
                            }
                            if (++i % 8 == 0) {
                                    pstmt.addBatch();// add batch
                            }
                            if (i % 80 == 0) {// insert when the batch size is 10
                                    pstmt.executeBatch();
                            }
                    }}
                    System.out.println("Data Successfully Uploaded");
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                    e.printStackTrace();
            }

    }
  }
```

**DBConnection.java**

```
package com.example.demo;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class DBConnection {

static {

    try {
        Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static Connection getConnection() throws SQLException {
 String url = "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;" +
      "databasename=myDBName;user=user;password=pwd;sendStringParametersAsUnicode=true;";    
 Connection con =DriverManager.getConnection(url);
    return con;

}


}
```